# How to count word frequencies for a word and combination of words in a CSV file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to process one particular column and I want to generate word cloud. for example, consider column name to be "names" .  I have 5 records under that column . They are "abc xyz" , "abc qpr xyz", "qpr xyz", "xyz" , "abc qpr" . So what I am expecting is like a tokenizer where I can get information as mentioned below: "abc" => 3 , "qpr" => 3, "xyz" => 4, "abc xyz" => 1 , "abc qpr xyz" => 1, "qpr xyz" => 2, "abc qpr" => 2. So I want to maintain frequencies for not a particular word but also for combination of words.

Comment: Can you please show the header along with some example rows? Is there one word per cell or multiple ones?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Can you show the code you have tried? Do you have a specific question with what you are having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you Patrick and Justin. I want to process one particular column and I want to generate word cloud. for example, consider column name to be "names" .  I have 5 records under that column . They are "abc xyz" , "abc qpr xyz", "qpr xyz", "xyz" , "abc qpr" . So what I am expecting is like a tokenizer where I can get information as mentioned below: "abc" => 3 , "qpr" => 3, "xyz" => 4, "abc xyz" => 1 , "abc qpr xyz" => 1, "qpr xyz" => 2, "abc qpr" => 2. So I want to maintain frequencies for not a particular word but also for combination of words.So, is there anyway in ruby to extract this info?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your CSV looks like this:

```
x,y,names,...
1,2,abc xyz,...
2,3,abc qpr xyz,...
3,4,qpr xyz,...
4,5,xyz,...
5,6,abc qpr,...
```

Here's one way to do it:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('data.csv', headers: true).with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |row, f|
  names = row['names']        # obtain names from csv row
  f[names] += 1               # increase counter for combined names
  names.split.each do |name|  # split names at whitespace
    f[name] += 1              # increase counter for single name
  end
end
#=> {"abc xyz"=>1, "abc"=>3, "xyz"=>5, "abc qpr xyz"=>1, "qpr"=>3, "qpr xyz"=>1, "abc qpr"=>1}
```

For customization, you might want to take a look at the documentation for the CSV library, there are tons of options available regarding the CSV format, header conversions etc.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I want to process one particular column and I want to generate word cloud. for example, consider column name to be "names" .  I have 5 records under that column . They are "abc xyz" , "abc qpr xyz", "qpr xyz", "xyz" , "abc qpr" . So what I am expecting is like a tokenizer where I can get information as mentioned below: "abc" => 3 , "qpr" => 3, "xyz" => 4, "abc xyz" => 1 , "abc qpr xyz" => 1, "qpr xyz" => 2, "abc qpr" => 2. So I want to maintain frequencies for not a particular word but also for combination of words. Is there any way I can extract this in ruby.?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- `str` is the String where you loaded the whole file.
- `num` is the column number that you wanted.

To have a Hash that counts all different combinations of names:

```
count = Hash.new(0)
str.split('\n').each do |line| 
    cols = line.split(',')
    count[cols[num]] += 1
end
return count
```

You instantiate a Hash object (`count`) that returns 0 by default, then add 1 for each key found.